# convert iphone to ipad but screen do not auto rotate while rotate the ipad

Tags: iphone, ios

I convert my tabbar based iphone app to ipad version with different ~ipad.xib, the only different is the ui element size. Now my question is that it can't auto rotate the screen in ipad version, i.e. I upsidedown the ipad, but the ui don't rotate upsidedown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return YES for the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` for all view controllers featured in your tab bar, for iPad only (`UI_INTERFACE_IDIOM()...`). The default code from your iPhone controllers probably only returns YES if it is portrait, if that is all you selected when initially creating the project.

Here is the code I use for this situation (iPhone, portrait only, iPad, all orientations):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        return YES;
    else
        return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tab bar controller can not auto rotate. you have to rotate all the component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to accomplish your task in case of universal apps

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations

    BOOL ret;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        // iPad-specific code

    if (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        ret = YES;
    }else{
        ret = NO;
    }
    } else  {
        // iPhone-specific code

    ret = YES;
    }

 return ret;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify 'Supported Device Orientations' to include your new orientations